Why is braid shield more efficient than a foil for low frequency noise?
I know that for lower frequencies the wave length is larger, but what happens to the noise that makes a braid more efficient than foil? Is it the amount of copper that is greater in the braid than in the foil?

From answers to my earlier question I got it regarding the high frequencies, but physically what makes the braid be more efficient in low frequencies? As the low frequency has larger wave length, how does it behave in the braid? Is this more efficient because the braid has a larger content of copper?

Bruno Pimenta - I see you have now started to ask the same question from here in comments on your earlier question. We don't want questions to cause duplicate effort, so I'm closing this one as a duplicate of that earlier question, since you are continuing there. || If you still want to ask a new question related to this in future, please link to the earlier question in any new question and explain how & why the answers to that earlier question are not sufficient.

I don't understand what you mean by "efficient" here.  Do you mean "efficacious"??
